# How do I change the transparency of an NSImage/NSImageView?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsimageview

I have a view in the menu bar into which I'm putting some images. I want to make it 50% transparent. I've tried:

```
let image = NSImage(named: "bar.pdf")
let imageView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3, height: 11))
imageView.wantsLayer = true
imageView.alphaValue = 0.5
```

However, the image is still completely opaque.

Comment: It works for me except that...  Where do you add that view?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet appears to be working in the playground. Is it possible that you are actually setting the `alphaValue` of one view but showing another? Also, setting the `alphaValue` of the view does not in its own right call for `wantsLayer` to be `true`. Finally, your code example is missing the line where you set the image of the view, though I cannot imagine how that could be relevant to your problem (the order in which you set these two properties does not matter)...

```
import XCPlayground
import Cocoa

let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfa20635c9269675d54547c080c9b64")!
let image = NSImage(contentsOfURL: url)!
let imageView = NSImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))
imageView.image = image
imageView.alphaValue = 0.5
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = imageView
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple changed some of the names of things in newer versions of swift:

Here's a Swift 3.0 version:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfa20635c9269675d54547c080c9b64")!
let image = NSImage(contentsOf: url)!
let imageView = NSImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))
imageView.image = image
imageView.alphaValue = 0.5
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
```